# Libpcap: Packet Filtration at word level

Tags: libpcap, jnetpcap

Using Libpcap I am trying to filter the Packet at word level. E.g I want to drop the packet if it has word "Hello".

How will I write the expression for that???

Answer (score 0):

I think I already answered you on the jNetPcap forum but just to make sure, I will also post my answer here on SO.

Basically here are several ways this filtering could be done. Since you didn't specify how exactly you want to "filter", I will describe a way with a low level capture filter and a filter in java.

#### Capture Header

If you only need to look at the **tcp payload** and **know the offset** at which "Hello" should appear, I would try the capture filter generator from Wireshark at https://www.wireshark.org/tools/string-cf.html - This allows you to create a string matching capture filter for the tcp payload.

In your example (assuming tcp payload offset of 0) the capture filter (in bpf syntax) would look like:

```
not (tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x48656c6c && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 4:1] = 0x6f)
```

Read the explanation on the linked page to know what exactly is going on. Note: I have added the **"not"** because we want to drop packets that match this filter and not the other way around.

You can use this filter in jNetPcap via `setFilter(PcapBpfProgram bpf)` on the Pcap object.

If you don't want to restrict yourself to the tcp payload and a fixed offset, you can't use capture filters and need to filter this packets in java code.

#### Filtering in Java

One example would be this simple jnetpcap packet handler:

```
public class PacketHandler implements PcapPacketHandler<Object> {
    @Override
    public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, Object unused) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        /* 
         Convert the whole packet (headers + payloads) to a string.
         Adjust the first and last parameter if you don't want to look at the whole packet
         */
        packet.getUTF8String(0, str, packet.getTotalSize());
        String rawStringData = str.toString();
        if (rawStringData.contains("Hello")) {
            // we have found a packet that contains the text "Hello"
            return; // ignore it
        }
        // do something with the packet that does not contain "Hello"
    }
}

[...]
// use packet handler
pcap.loop(numberOfPackets, new PacketHandler(), null);
```

You could also try the method `getUTF8Char(index)` if you know the starting offset of "Hello" and don't want to convert the whole packet or payload to a String.